# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0

Tags: c#, windows, powershell

I am building a application in C#, so far all it does is call the "get-process" powershell command.

I have edited the csproj file to include System.Management.Automation

```
<ItemGroup>
 <Reference Include="System.Management.Automation" />
```

When run locally (Windows 8.1 running Powershell version 4) it works.

When run on a remote Windows 7 machine with Powershell version 2, the program throws an exception

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

It cannot find System.Management.Automation Version=3.0.0.0. I was lead to believe that this would work on any version of Powershell and reference the local version

The cmdlet Get-Process does work on PS V2.

Is it possible to stop forcing version 3 of system management automation? I've read you can do this in the app.config but there is no reference to system management automation.

Thankyou for your time.

------------------------------------------------------ EDIT -----------------------------------------------

I was able to make this work but setting the Target framework to .Net 3.5, however this now forces PS V2. Is there anyway I can target the local version of the system management dll and make clients use that version?

Comment: are you able to simply update Powershell on the Windows 7 box? `> choco install Powershell` with [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/)

Comment: Well, you are going to have to target .NET 3.5 if you want PowerShell version 2 to be able to load the dll.

Comment: This seems a bit crap in the fact that by targetting NET 3.5 I am forcing every client to PowerShell 2 and PowerShell 2 only.. 

Surely there is another way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Powershell 2.0 does not include System.Management.Automation V3.  System.Management.Automation is provided by Windows Management Framework Core, not .Net.  If you've got Powershell 2.0, you do not have Automation 3.0.  For a list of what files/assemblies are provided in Powershell 2.0 visit the following site:

[Windows Management Framework (Windows PowerShell 2.0, WinRM 2.0, and BITS 4.0)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929)

Upgrade to Powershell 4.0 by installing WMF 4.0 from Microsoft on the target machine.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40855

Comment: Hi sorry I was away for the weekend, I have marked as answer. 

Is there anyway my program can work with both powershell version 3+ and version 2? seems impossible.

Comment: One of two things would need to occur.  Either rewrite the program for the 2.0 assembly, or upgrade the assembly so your program works natively.  Those are the only two options I know of :-/

Comment: my powershell version is 4.0 still getting this error

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem on a fully up to date Windows 10 system.

What solved it for me was installing the latest release of Powershell from here:

https://github.com/powershell/powershell