# PowerShell closing Immediately

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10

I have checked loads of different ways of fixing it (new user, sfc /scannow etc.) but PowerShell is still closing straight away with the error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please consider providing an example of the code that produces this error...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27515303/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-management-automation-version-3-0-0-0)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, in my case it worked with disabling third-party services in the task manager:

[PowerShell fails to start](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/powershell-fails-to-start/2f2d58e5-72c8-4c4a-af0e-6958c667aabb)